# Trying to output all the adjacent elements in a 2d array but only output is the size of the array

Tags: java, arrays, loops

```
    public ArrayList<GridCell> getAdjacent() {
        ArrayList<GridCell> results = new ArrayList<GridCell>();
        
        for (int r = this.getRow()-1; r<= this.getRow()+1; r++ ) {
            for(int c = this.getColumn() -1 ; c<= this.getColumn() +1 ;c++) {
                if (r == this.getRow()  &&  c == this.getColumn()) {
                    
                }
                else if (r < 0 ||  r > grid.getHeight() - 1 || c < 0 || c > grid.getWidth() - 1) {
                    
                }
                else {
                    results.add(grid.get(r,c));
                }
            }
        }
        return results;
    }
```

I tried to create a nested for loop to go on the adjacent rows and columns of the element and see if they are not out of bound or the actual element. It should output the locations of the elements but just output the size of the 2d array e.g 4x3.

this.getRows() and this.getColumns() repesents the coorditnated of the location of the element in the array that i want to find the adjacent elements of. for example (3,1) is the element to find the adjacent and the size of the array is 4 rows by 3 colunms and currenlty  the ouput is currently an arraylist with 1 value of (4,3) but i expect it to be an arraylist with the values (3,0)(3,2)(2,0)(2,1)(2,2).

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include a [example]. It would be helpful to also see your inputs, expected output and actual output.

Answer (score 0):

We can't tell what's wrong with your code as we can't see all those supporting functions and whether they are implemented correctly, as well as how you're testing the results to see if they are correct.

I'd start, though, with re-writing your `getAdjacent()` function so it's easier to read and understand:

```
public ArrayList<GridCell> getAdjacent() {
    ArrayList<GridCell> results = new ArrayList<GridCell>();

    int curRow = this.getRow();
    int r1 = Math.Max(0, curRow-1);
    int r2 = Math.Min(grid.getHeight()-1, curRow+1);
  
    int curCol = this.getColumn();
    int c1 = Math.Max(0, curCol-1);
    int c2 = Math.Min(grid.getWidth()-1, curCol+1);
  
    for (int r = r1; r <= r2; r++) {
        for(int c = c1; c <= c2; c++) {
            if ( !(r == curRow && c == curCol) ) {
                results.add(grid.get(r,c));
            }
        }
    }
  
    return results;
}
```

If `getRow()` or `getColumn()` give coordinates that are NOT within the bounds of the array, should it return an empty ArrayList? What if those coords are just outside the bounds and some the adjacent neighbors are within bounds? Should those coords within the bounds still be returned even when the starting coords are outside bounds?

This version has the benefit that you can now inspect `curRow`, `curCol`, `r1`, `r2`, `c1`, and `c2` to see if those values are what you're expecting. This will tell you if those supporting functions are working correctly.